# What approaches faster?

Tags: calculus, limits

We know that if we have, for example, exponential function in the numerator and square function in the denominator, and both approach infinity, then the limit is infinity since exponential function approaches infinity faster.
Let's consider

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {e^x} × \frac{1}{x}$

I know this aprroaches infinity since we can write it as ${e^x}/{x}$ but as I can't think of a better example this has to do it.
My question is can we conclude that limit is infinity without any transformations, in general case, if multiplicand aproaches infinity faster then multiplier approaches $0$?

Comment: If a numerator approaches $0$ and denominator $\infty$, the relative rate of approaching doesn't matter, it'll be $0$ regardless.

Comment: If the numerator goes to $0$ and the denominator goes to infinity, then the fraction goes to $0$, period.

Comment: What if we had product of two functions , one approaches infinity and other $0$. and the second one approaches faster then the first? Would limit be $0$?

Comment: If you are able to quantify "approaches faster than the first" with rigorous definitions, you should be able to answer that question yourself.  The end result is that "$0\cdot \infty$" is one of those indeterminate forms which requires closer analysis.

Comment: Of course, $e^x\cdot \frac1x$ can be written as $\frac{e^x}{x}$ which is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}.$ In general, most limits of the form $\infty\cdot 0$ can be written as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the definition of the limit. You want to show that, for any $A > 0$, there exists $x_0$ such that $x > x_0 \Rightarrow f(x) > A$.

Now, if I understand correctly, you sak whether you can split the problem when $f(x) = g(x) \times h(x)$ and study separately each, with $g(x)$ going to infinity.

If you can bound $h(x)$ from below, $h(x)>\varepsilon>0$, knowing $g$ goes to infinity you can find an $x_0$ from which $g(x) > \frac{A}{\varepsilon}$ and so $f(x) > A$.

But if $h(x)$ tends to zero, then you cannot make this lower bound on $h(x)$ and thus need to compare $g$ and $h$ pointwise, so make the product in some way.

Comment: If we have something that goes to infinity in numerator and something that goes to infinity in denominator but numerator approaches infinity faster we conclude that limit is infinity since numerator approaches infinity faster. My question is can we use  this reasoning for other indeterminate cases?( I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense, my general knowledge of english is pretty decent, but with math terminology it's a bit trickier)

Comment: You can use the above: if your ratio can be written $n(x) / d(x) = g(x) h(x)$ with one of the functions bounded from above (resp. from below) and the other one going to 0 (resp to +infinity), then you can show that the product goes to 0 (resp to infinity). (Take care in case the ratio is negative, buttthis is the spirit)